# How to disable directory listing in Next js deployed to Vercel

Tags: next.js, vercel

I have deployed website built in `Next.js` and apparently when you deploy a next js app you can find the directory of all the static files and resources which i don't feel very good about.

the directory is generated in this way:  `mydomain.com/_next/static` in my case `https://www.ovanya.com/_next/static/`

this is the directory:
[image]

the next js [docs](https://vercel.com/docs/directory-listing) say:

> To prevent showing a Directory Listing page, add an index file, such as index.html, which will then show that file instead when accessing the directory's path.

but i really don't understand what directory should i add the index.html file to? so where should i exatcly put the index.html at?

and another question: is it bad if i leave this just like that? does it have any risks or stuff like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**2021 Update**

You can disable directory listing in Project settings -> Advanced (see [docs](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/edge-network/directory-listing)).

**Before 2021**

You need to add `index.html` to `_next` and every child directory recursively. You could do it by writing a post-build script that would do it.

But, there is **no benefit** doing so. There is **no risk** of exposing this directory or files inside it.

`_next/static` is just compiled client-side public assets.

Comment: so why are they offering a password protection for this ? i don't get it ? do you have any idea ?

Comment: @mangrove108, see the updated answer. You can disable it in the settings.

Comment: yes exactly what i was looking for, havent seen the 404 in api, thanks a lot 

Answer (score 2):

I'm also looking for solution and have tried to create custom post-build script but didn't work. My final solution is creating redirect rules in `vercel.json` file in your root project directory.

This is my `vercel.json`

```
{
  "redirects": [
    {
      "source": "/_next",
      "destination": "/404",
      "statusCode": 404
    },
    {
      "source": "/_next/static",
      "destination": "/404",
      "statusCode": 404
    },
    {
      "source": "/_next/static/([A-z0-9_-]{21})",
      "destination": "/404",
      "statusCode": 404
    },
    {
      "source": "/_next/static/chunks",
      "destination": "/404",
      "statusCode": 404
    },
    {
      "source": "/_next/static/css",
      "destination": "/404",
      "statusCode": 404
    },
    {
      "source": "/_next/static/images",
      "destination": "/404",
      "statusCode": 404
    }
  ]
}
```

You can check at [Vercel Dashboard](https://vercel.com/dashboard) > Your Project Deployment > Source > Output, if you have other directories to hide.

Once you deploy your site with this configuration, you will get 404 page rendered when you visit that URL.